# Javafx button text not showing

Tags: java, button, javafx

I'm currently creating a layout in JavaFX. However, the text of my buttons is showing in some places and for some buttons the text is just showing as '...'. 
I want to display the whole text in the buttons while keeping the window size as 500x500. 
Here's my code, I'm creating 10 buttons and only some of them are showing their text. Is there any way to set the button sizes constant throught the layout while also displaying their text?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainGUI extends Application {
    private Button[] buttons=new Button[10];
    private Stage window;
    private GridPane layout;
    public int count=3;
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage)
    {
        window=primaryStage;
        layout=new GridPane();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(100));
        layout.setVgap(10);
        layout.setHgap(10);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            buttons[i]=new Button();
        }
        buttons[0].setText("y=0.5x");
        buttons[1].setText("y=x");
        buttons[2].setText("y=2x");
        buttons[3].setText("y=0.1x^2");
        buttons[4].setText("y=x^2");
        buttons[5].setText("y=10x^2");
        buttons[6].setText("y=3 sin(x pi/10)");
        buttons[7].setText("y=6 sin(x pi/10)");
        buttons[8].setText("y=6 sin(x pi/5)");
        buttons[9].setText("y= 5 sin(x pi/10) + (5/3)sin(3x pi/10) + sin(x pi/2) + (5/7)sin(7x pi/10)");

        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            if (count==3)
            {
                count=0;
            }
            if(j<=2)
            {
                GridPane.setConstraints(buttons[j],count,0);
            }
            else if ((j>2) && (j<=5))
            {
                GridPane.setConstraints(buttons[j],count,1);
            }
            else if((j>5) && (j<=8))
            {
                GridPane.setConstraints(buttons[j],count,2);
            }
            else if((j>8) && (j<=9))
            {
                GridPane.setConstraints(buttons[j],1,3);
            }
            count++;
        }
        layout.getChildren().addAll(buttons);
        Scene scene=new Scene(layout,600,600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the minWidth() of your buttons...

Comment: I was using minSize all this time. Thanks for the headsup!

Comment: If you set the page width to 600 or 700 it is working?

Comment: I do not see `minSize` or `minWidth` anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it looks with 0 insets :

[image]

As you can see it is quiet tight. 
An easy alternative would be to make the last long button span over two columns:

```
GridPane.setConstraints(buttons[j],1,3,2,1);
```

Which results in

[image]

For more control over the layout consider using some child panes. For example:

[image]